# Sind in Österreich und der Schweiz „riechen“ und „schmecken“ Synonyme?

Tags: meaning-in-context, austrian, swiss-german

Ich glaube, ein paar mal gehört zu haben, dass Köche bei Kochsendungen (u.Ä.) gesagt haben, etwas habe gut *gerochen*, wenn sie das Aroma bzw. den Geschmack von dem, was sie gerade gegessen haben, beschreiben wollten.  Diese Köche waren alle aus dem südlichen Teil des deutschen Sprachgebiets.  
Irre ich mich?  Ich habe sowohl bei Duden im Wörterbuch als auch im Synonymwörterbuch nachgeschlagen, und in diesen Werken bezieht sich das verb *riechen* nur auf das, was man mit der Nase macht.  
Was meint ihr?

Comment: *etwas riecht gut" wie in deiner Frage gefragt als Synonym für *schmeckt gut* kenne ich nicht. Andersrum schon - *schmeckt fei* kann auf schwäbisch sowohl "riecht gut" als auch "schmeckt gut" heissen.

Comment: Und gerade aus dem Schwäbischen sollte in diesem Kontext auch [*Gschmäckle*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gschmäckle) erwähnt werden - benutzt für Vorgänge "mit Beigeschmack" oder etwas "anrüchigem" Charakter. Zeigt schön den Dualismus von riechen/schmecken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Umgekehrt:

Wenn im Süddeutschen oder Schweizerdeutsch "schmecken" oder "Geschmack" *in der jeweiligen Dialektausprägung* benutzt wird, kann das sich sowohl auf den *Geschmack*, als auch auf den *Geruch* beziehen - aus dem Kontext sollte klar werden, was gemeint ist.

Die Fernsehköche oder Testesser dagegen haben lediglich das Gericht nach verschiedenen sensorischen Eindrücken bewertet und da ist der Geruch einer Speise eben einer davon.

Comment: Hast vielleicht Recht.  Ich konzentriere mich das nächste Mal viel besser.  *lach  Das mit „schmecken“ ist mir noch nicht aufgefallen.  Interessant, aber.  Danke.

Comment: Dies ist zwar richtig, aber manche Leute (u.a. ich) unterscheiden "schmecka" (sensorisches Empfinden *während des Essens*, auch den Geruch) und "schmöcka" (ausschliesslich riechen)

Comment: Meine Eltern sagten noch ganz klar *schmecka* für riechen. Weil das ausserhalb des Dialekts aber keiner versteht, stirbt die Verwendung in weniger dialektgeprägten Gegenden (Großstadt) langsam aus. Eine Unterscheidung wie von @caconym erwähnt, kenne ich nicht.

Comment: Die Verwechslung passiert den besten Österreichern... ein Bauer aus dem Lungau hat mich einmal sehr entgeistert angeschaut, als ich einen Halm Silagefutter in den Mund genommen habe, nachdem er über dessen eigenartigen "Geschmack" erzählt hat...